# Can a software upgrade ever be non-incremental?

Tags: upgrade, patch

Normally all our upgrades, feature or bug-fix, are incremental. This seems obvious because even to develop a bug-fix we take the latest code-base of our product. However, this leads to a requirement that our customers have to update the software to the latest version even to get a bug-fix, they get the features as well as bug-fixes.

Recently, customers are telling us that they want the ability to get bug-fix patches without having to use new feature enhancements. Basically they want the bug to be fixed but they don't want new features. This is a dilemma for us. This is possible if the bug-fix changes a different set of binaries than the features. However, many times the features and bug-fixes are in the same binaries.

Is it even possible to create an upgrade that can be applied on any software version independently? Do others do this? Are Microsoft or Office KB patches ever non-incremental? Any guidance or links to relevant articles are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is easier if you think in terms of branches. You have a branch for each major version of your product, and a branch for each of the fixes. You can apply the fix branch to each of your major version branches (or only to those to which the fix makes sense). It could be that you need to do some specific modifications though.

Comment: It would then be a case-to-case development according to which customer is on which version? The problem is every-time a merge is done QA effort will be duplicated.

Comment: I really can't see a problem here. You can make those new features optional and make them switchable by some kind of preferences dialog or command line options. You can even make a process that asks users which of the new features they want to enable after each update.

Comment: I knew someone would point this out. But the features have evolved way too ahead. Some of them are a complete revamp and we want to deprecate old features; keeping them configurable would then mean us having to maintain both the new and old features. We want customers to be forced to get the modern features, which is reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Release Strategies](https://www.renemoser.net/blog/2016/01/09/release-strategies/) on the Rene Moser blog may be helpful.

The LTS (Long Time Supported Versions) section seems applicable to your concerns.

Regarding your questions:

- Is it even possible to create an upgrade that can be applied on any
  software version independently? - Sure, but it takes extra time, effort and money (usually).
- Do others do this? - Yes.
- Are Microsoft or Office KB patches ever non-incremental? - Yes, for major releases; but not KB patches.

A follow up question: is it worthwhile to do the extra work to facilitate non-incremental software releases for your software users?

The answer to this questions depends on your customer base, which may require a long meeting with the software developers and those in Marketing. If the customers wanting non-incremental releases are significant in terms of their numbers and revenue, then the extra work is probably necessary to keep those customers.

Comment: Thanks @JohnH, LTS seems to be close enough to our needs. Your answer and the Blog link has helped clear up a lot of confusion I had about this. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

What the customer wants is normal but that does not mean that this is an easy problem.

What you describe is at the heart of configuration management. SCM is not just using a tool like git, it is using such a tool to solve the needs present. There is no silver bullet, to meet configuration requests take a lot of work and preparation of your code. I see that you have not tagged this as configuration management; this is exactly what you need to research if you have not.

Back to your specific request: The customer wants to be able to release bug fixes without the features you are continually working on. For the purposes of this answer I will assume your business model is that you offer a product which is a living thing and that several customers 'subscribe' to.

#### Branching strategy based on customer

Customer X, Y, and Z all gets different branches. Along with a developing branch from which you can pull features/bug fixes to the customers that want them.

This solution I would say is often very challenging (SCM generally is), you have to deal with diverging codebases and the developers have to be very aware of your work-flow.

#### Release branches

Having a branch for every released version which you can patch with bug fixes while not bringing in the new features is what I suggest. You're question is a bit unclear what you mean by incremental, if this somehow refer to the distribution of the patches itself then that is another matter and this answer will be less useful.

#### Feature-flags

You deliver new features to the customer which do not want them but they are hidden behind logic in your application. This can be hard to combine with what you describe as 'complete revamp'. This can also have other advantages as it makes it easy to perform [A-B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing).

It places requirements on your architecture and also discipline when it comes to what to allow, too many feature flags for every little thing and it can get un-maintainable.

#### Have a strategy

You need to plan for this or you can not satisfy your customers needs. And it may be very well that if you have customers who wants the wrong things you have to negotiate. But providing bug-fixes without new features I think is the minimum

The books I read on this is *old*, but here is one i remember anyway: Wayne A Babich: Software Configuration Management - Coordination for Team Productivity

Comment: Thanks @Adam, your answer is much help. I'll read up more about SCM. As you said, I wasn't even aware of these terms. I ended up with lot of futile search before posting this question. Cheers!

Comment: About incremental, it was in relation to code branches and not patches. Currently we have a single master branch, so any change is incremental.